# Relative Time Series

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for a standardized method for arranging data in relative time. Applications include accounting data such as FY1,FY2,etc... and economic data such as the term structure of interest rates using the 1 year, 2 year, 3 year, etc...

I would like to be able to compare a set of time series data that is current and several historic time series sets that represent similar situations or historic norms. I was looking at xts but it looks like I need to use an absolute time reference.

I would eventually like to use Quantmod's charting functions or graphs with equivalent capability to visualize the data. Since chartSeries requires a time series object, does anyone know how to do this? Even a point in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks.

```
require(quantmod)
symbols=c("DGS1","DGS2","DGS3","DGS5","DGS7","DGS10","DGS20")
getSymbols(symbols,src="FRED")
one.h=mean(na.omit(DGS1));two.h=mean(na.omit(DGS2));three.h=mean(na.omit(DGS3));five.h=mean(na.omit(DGS5));seven.h=mean(na.omit(DGS7));ten.h=mean(na.omit(DGS10));twenty.h=mean(na.omit(DGS20))
historic=c(one.h,two.h,three.h,five.h,seven.h,ten.h,twenty.h)
current=c(last(DGS1),last(DGS2),last(DGS3),last(DGS5),last(DGS7),last(DGS10),last(DGS20))
years=c(1,2,3,5,7,10,20)
plot(years,current,type="o",pch=20,ann=FALSE)
lines(years,historic,type="o",pch=20,col="red",lty=3)
title(main="Term Structure of Interest Rates",col.main="red", font.main=4)
title(xlab="Years to Maturity",ylab="Interest Rate",col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
legend(3, c("Current","Historic"),cex=0.8,col=c("black","red"),pch=20)
```

Problem:
I would like to be able to select a time period such as September of 2007 and grab each daily yield curve to plot against the current yield curve. I'm sure I could use several pages of first and last functions but that would be more work than building it in Excel.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Could you provide an example?

Comment: by 'relative time' do you mean you start with, for example, Jan 1, 1980 is t=0? And each period after that is t+n?

Comment: Yes. Ideally the scale would be variable so that the "n" in "t+n" could be assignable to days, years, quarters, etc... An accounting example would be current fiscal quarter = 0, next fiscal quarter = 1 in order to compare various metrics for companies with different fiscal years and create a standardized framework for forecasts. Another application would be comparing bond curves where I could compare various sets of maturities from different points in history or using averages for each maturity for a subset of historical data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xts` requires an explicit time index but it's based on `zoo`, which has no such requirement.  So `zoo` will allow you to do something like this, as long as the index is ordered:

```
> x <- zoo(rnorm(5),sprintf("FY%02d",1:5))
> y <- zoo(rnorm(5),sprintf("FY%02d",1:5))
> merge(x,y)
               x           y
FY01  0.32707886 -1.81414982
FY02 -0.95177700  0.37772862
FY03 -0.03052571 -1.13047719
FY04  1.19139973  0.96962871
FY05 -0.76484142 -0.08187144
```

The downside is that you won't be able to use those objects with `quantmod::chartSeries` because it requires an `xts` object.  I doubt this answers your question, but I hope it gives you some ideas.

EDIT to incorporate OP's example:

```
library(quantmod)
symbols=c("DGS1","DGS2","DGS3","DGS5","DGS7","DGS10","DGS20")
getSymbols(symbols,src="FRED")
all <- na.omit(merge(DGS1,DGS2,DGS3,DGS5,DGS7,DGS10,DGS20))

years <- c(1,2,3,5,7,10,20)
# use xts indexing, since getSymbols returns xts
histDate <- "2007-09-01/2007-09-10"
# create zoo objects for non-time-based indexing
hist <- zoo(t(all[histDate]), order.by=years)
curr <- zoo(t(last(all)), order.by=years)

currHist <- merge(curr,hist)
plotCol <- rainbow(NCOL(currHist))
plot(currHist, screens=1, col=plotCol, pch=20, type="o", ann=FALSE)
title(main="Term Structure of Interest Rates",col.main="red", font.main=4)
title(xlab="Years to Maturity",ylab="Interest Rate",col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
legend(15,1.5,colnames(currHist),cex=0.8,col=plotCol,pch=20)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to realize why so few people in finance don't go beyond Excel.

Comment: Don't kid yourself; it's not limited to people in finance.  ;-)  Someone could probably provide a better solution if you could give an example of the problem you're trying to solve.  And since `chartSeries` wasn't designed for the type of problem you have, try `plot.zoo(..., screens=1)`.

Comment: Thanks! Learning "merge" definitely shortens a lot!